# Create a multiple of vsftpd.conf

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ftp, docker, vsftpd

my vsftpd is working fine but only for one domaine ! that i can create multiple users. So now i want that a can create a vsftpd for a multiple domaine and then i will need to get a multiple config ...

i create a file in

```
/etc/vsftpd_conf/mydomaine_1/vsftpd.conf
```

and i want to create

```
/etc/vsftpd_conf/mydomaine_2/vsftpd.conf
```

but when i restart my vsftp i think that my server execute only this file

> `4313 /usr/sbin/vsftpd /etc/vsftpd.conf`

how can i change it to execute

```
/etc/vsftpd_conf/mydomaine_1 2 3 ..../vsftpd.conf
```

thanx for help

Comment: Add user in `/etc/vsftpd.conf` so

Comment: how ?? i didn't understand you

Comment: in one domaine i will have a lot of users

Answer (score 0):

What you may be trying to do is called ***multihoming***.

*"Sometimes, one computer is used to serve multiple FTP domains. This is a technique called multihoming. One way to multihome using vsftpd is by running multiple copies of the daemon, each with its own configuration file."* - [from 21.2.2. The vsftpdServer - Red Hat](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/deployment_guide/s2-ftp-servers-vsftpd)

Basically, you create multiple copies of your original `vsftpd.conf` file, each one listening to the IP address of a different FTP server:

```
# When "listen" directive is enabled, vsftpd runs in standalone mode and
# listens on IPv4 sockets. This directive cannot be used in conjunction
# with the listen_ipv6 directive.
listen=192.168.x.x
```

Starting the `vsftpd` service will start all the configurations.

This should work for both Fedora and Debian distros. Good luck and **make sure you back up your `vsftpd.conf` file first!**